# SSIS or Sql job dynamic start time

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, sql-job

How do i configure a SQL job or SSIS package to fire/ run in different timings defined in a column in table.

**Core Problem:**

I have a table with a notification system, where note appearance is dependant on status(*is it read / Updated / Closed / delay in any of those statuses*).
I need a job/SSIS to trigger every 10 minutes when isOpened Flag = 0.
when isOpened = 1 and isUpdated = 0 run job/SSIS every 15 minutes after 30 minutes from turning isOpened to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the desired answer online on the below URL:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3052/simple-way-to-create-a-sql-server-job-using-tsql/

Comment: Looking for the same urk after a year :)

Answer (score 0):

Do configure package for generic time interval(10 min) and Inside SSIS package add a variable.

top of your package add "Execute SQL task"

Using Execute SQL task you can assign the variable value and allow it to remaining package based on that variable value.

Comment: Could you please explain more the below phrase
 "Using Execute SQL task you can assign the variable value and allow it to remaining package based on that variable value"

Comment: I meant expression based on variable value by using expression you can allow your package to run

Comment: Thank you Santhana